# Flatten XML using XML transform with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Could anyone please help me with the following XML to XML transformation using XSLT?

Need to Split the worker tag based on <Effective_change> tag,a worker can have multiple effective changeand company can have multiple worker too.Each worker should be sorted based on  tag in effective change.

Here's the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <summary>
        <company_name>C1</company_name>
    </summary>
    <worker>
        <worker_summary>
            <Name>User 1</Name>
        </worker_summary>
        <Effective_Change sequence="0">
            <time>2022-01-01T07:00:00.000-09:00</time>
            <example>
                <content>User 1 Example 1 Content</content>
            </example>
        </Effective_Change>
        <Effective_Change sequence="1">
            <time>2022-01-01T02:00:00.000-09:00</time>
            <example>
                <content>User 1 Example 2 Content</content>
            </example>
        </Effective_Change>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <worker_summary>
            <Name>User 2</Name>
        </worker_summary>
        <Effective_Change sequence="0">
            <time>2022-02-01T11:00:00.000-09:00</time>
            <example>
                <content>User 2 Example 1 Content</content>
            </example>
        </Effective_Change>
    </worker>
</company>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <summary>
        <company_name>C1</company_name>
    </summary>
    <worker>
        <worker_summary>
            <Name>User 1</Name>
        </worker_summary>
        <Effective_Change>
            <time>2022-01-01T02:00:00.000-09:00</time>
            <example>
                <content>Example 1 Content</content>
            </example>
        </Effective_Change>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <worker_summary>
            <Name>User 1</Name>
        </worker_summary>
        <Effective_Change>
            <time>2022-01-01T07:00:00.000-09:00</time>
            <example>
                <content>Example 2 Content</content>
            </example>
        </Effective_Change>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <worker_summary>
            <Name>User 2</Name>
        </worker_summary>
        <Effective_Change sequence="0">
            <time>2022-02-01T11:00:00.000-09:00</time>
            <example>
                <content>User 2 Example 1 Content</content>
            </example>
        </Effective_Change>
    </worker>
</company>
```

Comment: You want to split each `worker` element into multiple `worker` elements, so that each one has only a single `Effective_Change` child element, and you want to duplicate the `worker_summary` child element in each of the new `worker` elements? Can you clarify the sort order ("tag in effective change"), please? Do you want to sort each `worker` by its `Effective_Change/time` or `Effective_Change/@sequence`, or what? Have you made an attempt at an XSLT yourself?

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: @ConalTuohy I want to sort by  Effective_Change/time , I haven't worked on XML or XSLT's before eventhough i tried to understand XSLT's but missing some of the tags while transforming

Comment: @ConalTuohy should I need to use for-each loop or directly match with template?     thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly, my advice would be:

Add a template that matches `worker` elements and does nothing but use `xsl:for-each` to iterate over the `Effective_Change` elements, with an `xsl:sort` that sorts them by `@time`, and construct a new `worker` element for each `Effective_Change`, populating it with the appropriate child elements.

```xml
<xsl:template match="worker">
  <!-- create a worker element once for each Effective_Change -->
  <xsl:for-each select="Effective_Change">
    <xsl:sort select="time"/>
    <xsl:copy select="parent::worker"><!-- copy the worker element -->
       <!-- add the Effective_Change's sibling worker_summary to the copied worker -->
       <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::worker_summary"/>
       <!-- copy the current Effective_Change -->
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

... and use an identity template for everything else.